# Cloning a <select> without one <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box with all european countries in there, the idea is that a person picks one or more countries that he/she does his/her business in.

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

And this is the javascript function:

```
function AddCountry(element) {

    var oldSelect = jQuery("select[name='investor-country[]']").last();
    var newSelect = jQuery(oldSelect).clone();

    jQuery(element).before(newSelect);
}
```

So when the person clicks on the Add country link, the javascript gets executed and another <select> is inserted above the link (the links is also the parameter being sent). This is an exact copy of the one before. The thing is I want it to remove the previous selected company from the list so the user can not (without having HTML knowlegde) enter two of the same countries.

I tried alot but haven't succeeded. I tried all kind of weird jQuery combinations but mainly:

```
newSelect.remove(0);
```

As far as I could find this should remove the first option from the list (0 can be replace with selectedIndex later) but it doesn't!

Comment: And you can't use `<select multiple>`? :)

Comment: Ooh yeah I forgot, this doesn't fit in the design.. so yeah, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function AddCountry(element) {

    var oldSelect = jQuery("select[name='investor-country[]']").last();
    var newSelect = jQuery(oldSelect).clone();

    // Remove previously selected option
    var selected = oldSelect.val();
    newSelect.find("option[value="+selected+"]").remove();

    jQuery(element).before(newSelect);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Why is the .find() needed though?

Comment: You could use `.children()` instead. But you need some function to find the option using the selector.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that `newSelect.children()[oldSelect.selectedIndex].remove();` doesn't work because it can't find the selectedIndex for some reason.

Comment: That should be `newSelect.children().eq(oldSelect.selectedIndex).remove()`. Using array indexing returns DOM elements, not jQuery objects.

Comment: Actually, it should be: `newSelect.children().eq(oldSelect[0].selectedIndex).remove()`. `oldSelect` is a jQuery object, `.selectedIndex` is an attribute of the DOM element.

Comment: Right, I need to learn the differences, going to look into that. Thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of removing the selected option:

```
newSelect.find('option').eq(oldSelect[0].selectedIndex).remove();
```

Comment: `newSelect[0]` should be `oldSelect[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    //get the selected value
    var val = $("select[name='investor-country[]']").val();
    //get the selected option
    var option = $("option[value="+val+"]");
    //append the selected country somewhere
    $('#selected').append('<span>'+option.text()+'</span> ');
    //remove the selected option
    option.remove();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EzSSj/)